# Como fazer select em 3 tabelas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso fazer `SELECT` em duas tabelas com relacionamento `n` para `n`, logo, terei de fazer uso da tabela intermediária também, porém não sei como fazer isso. Estou utilizando PHP e banco de dados SQLServer.

Comment: Se você não informar quais tabelas e quais dados dessas tabelas, fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Utilize o `join` e o sabor(`inner`, `right` etc) adequado para os resultados esperados.

Answer (score 6):

Voce precisa relacionar as 3 tabelas através do comando JOIN
Veja um simples exemplo.

```
SELECT * FROM tabelaA a
INNER JOIN tabelaRelacao r on a.id_tabelaA = r.id_tabelaA
INNER JOIN tabelaB b on a.id_tabelaB = r.id_tabelaB
```

Segue uma imagem que representa graficamente a Utilização dos `joins`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mais detalhado que isso não poderia :)

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa fazer o uso de [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) na sua consulta.

```
SELECT
    T.ID_Tabela1,
    T.Descricao,
    T3.Descricao
FROM Tabela1 T
INNER JOIN
    Tabela2 T2 ON T2.ID_Tabela2 = T.ID_Tabela2
INNER JOIN
    Tabela3 T3 ON T3.ID_Tabela3 = T2.ID_Tabela3
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos dar um exemplo:

Você tem um objeto Artigo que tem mais de um categoria, e uma categoria pode ter mais de um artigo.

Neste exemplo eu quero pegar 10 artigos com todas as categorias.

```
SELECT * FROM artigo

LEFT JOIN artigo_categorias ON (artigo.id = artigo_categorias.artigo_id)
LEFT JOIN categorias ON (artigo_categorias.categoria_id = categoria_id)

LIMIT 10
```

Neste caso bastaria você fazer a chamada que você faz no PHP chamando este SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize joins:

Inner Join: Registro obrigatório em A e B
Left Join: Registro obrigatório em A, B pode ser null
Right Join: Registro obrigatório em B, A pode ser null

Tutorial: http://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-associacao-de-tabelas-sql-server-2008-parte-2/18930

```
SELECT
    t1.nome, t1.id01, t2.id01, t2.id02, t3.curso, t3.id02
FROM
    TABELA01 t1
    INNER JOIN TABELA02 t2
    ON t1.id01 = t2.id01
    INNER JOIN TABELA 03 t3
    ON t2.id02 = t3.id02
```