# Duvida de relacionamento de tabelas

Tags: sql-server

Bom dia gostaria de uma ajuda de como faço para obter duas informações em uma tabela partindo de outra.
exemplo tenho uma tabela de notas onde tenho o ID_agente e o ID_endereco, quero pegar o nome do agente e o nome do cliente na tabela pessoas cujo campo chave é pessoas.cgccpf.

Para ter o cgccpf do agente preciso relacionar o id_agente da nota com a tabela usuarios pelo id_agente
Para ter o cgccpf do cliente tenho que relacionar o id_endereco com a tabela endereco pelo id_endereco.
Ate aqui tudo bem 
inner join agentes on agente.id_agente       = notas.id_agente
inner join endereco on endereco.id_endereco  = notas.id_endereco

Porem como pego o endereco.cgccpf e o agente.cgccpf em ambas e mostro os nomes de cada um que esta na tabela pessoas ?

```
CREATE TABLE Notas (
    id_nfcapa integer NOT NULL,
    cgccpf decimal(14,0) NOT NULL,
    tppessoa smallint NULL,
    nronota integer NOT NULL,
    serienf char(4) NOT NULL, 
    nro_endere decimal(17,0) NOT NULL, -- FK Endereço
    id_agente integer NOT NULL -- FK Agente
);

CREATE TABLE Agentes (
    id_agente integer NOT NULL, -- PK Agente
    id_setor integer NOT NULL, 
    tppessoa smallint NOT NULL, 
    cgccpf decimal(14,0) NOT NULL, -- FK Pessoa
    cargo smallint NOT NULL
);  

CREATE TABLE Endereco (
    nro_endere decimal(17,0) NULL, -- PK Endereço
    cgccpf decimal(14,0) NOT NULL, -- FK Pessoa
    tppessoa smallint NOT NULL,  
    seqendereco smallint NOT NULL,  
    tipoendereco char(1) NULL, 
    endereco char(30) NULL, 
    complemento char(10) NULL
);  

CREATE TABLE Pessoas (
    cgccpf decimal(14,0) NOT NULL, -- PK Pessoa
    tppessoa smallint NOT NULL,  
    nomepessoa char(40) NULL,  
    nomeguerra char(20) NULL,  
    dtfundacao date NULL,  
    rg char(14) NULL, 
);
```

Obrigado

Ronie

Comment: o id_agente não relaciona com pessoas.id?

Comment: Você quer obter o cgccpf do endereço e do agente, e ambos são diferentes, correto?

Comment: poste a estrutura de suas tabelas, caso mas antes de uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99874/como-fazer-select-em-3-tabelas/99877#99877

Comment: poste um print da estrutura de suas tabelas

Comment: Notas:
Column name          Type                                    Nulls

id_nfcapa            integer                                 no
cgccpf               decimal(14,0)                           no
tppessoa             smallint                                yes
nronota              integer                                 no
serienf              char(4)                                 no
nro_endere           decimal(17,0)                           no     <---
id_agente            integer                                 no     <---

Comment: Agentes

Column name          Type                                    Nulls
id_agente            integer                                 no     <----
id_setor             integer                                 no
tppessoa             smallint                                no
cgccpf               decimal(14,0)                           no
cargo                smallint                                no

Comment: Endereco

Column name          Type                                    Nulls
nro_endere           decimal(17,0)                           yes    <-----
cgccpf               decimal(14,0)                           no
tppessoa             smallint                                no
seqendereco          smallint                                no
tipoendereco         char(1)                                 yes
endereco             char(30)                                yes
complemento          char(10)                                yes

Comment: Pessoas:
Column name          Type                                    Nulls
cgccpf               decimal(14,0)                           no      <---
tppessoa             smallint                                no
nomepessoa           char(40)                                yes
nomeguerra           char(20)                                yes
dtfundacao           date                                    yes
rg                   char(14)                                yes

Comment: Devido ao limite de caracteres estas são partes das estruturas com os atributos que interessam.

Comment: @Ronie, movi os seus comentarios para a sua pergunta, assim como tentei torna-los mais legiveis, então por favor confira a minha edição.

Answer (score 0):

Para ter o cgccpf do cliente tenho que relacionar o id_endereco com a tabela endereco pelo id_endereco.

Por que o cgcpfg do cliente fica na tabela endereco ?? não deveria ficar na tabela de usuarios?

Answer (score 0):

Tentei entender a sua estrutura apartir dos seus comentarios, então acredito que o seguinte select resolva o seu problema:

```
SELECT 
    Notas.id_nfcapa,
    Notas.cgccpf,
    Notas.tppessoa,
    Notas.nronota,
    Notas.serienf,
    PesCliente.nomepessoa,
    PesAgente.nomepessoa
FROM Notas
JOIN Agentes ON Notas.id_agente = Agentes.id_agente
JOIN Endereco ON Notas.nro_endere = Endereco.nro_endere
JOIN Pessoas as PesAgente ON Agentes.cgccpf = PesAgente.cgccpf
JOIN Pessoas as PesCliente ON Endereco.cgccpf = PesCliente.cgccpf
```

**BONUS - Sugestões**

O Texto abaixo não faz parte da resposta, é apenas algumas sugestões complementares para o AP.

Em todo caso, gostaria de te aconselhar a seguinte leitura [Choosing a Primary Key: Natural or Surrogate?](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html), eu particulamente não gosto de ter `chaves naturais` como primarias... Em 90% dos casos, ter uma `chave substituta` (sem valor para o negocio) que seja `IDENTITY` com um `Clustred Index` associado como PK é a melhor opção.

Outro ponto, não sei como está a sua estrutura, mas é interresante você criar um FK para estes relacionamentos, e um indice para cada relacionamento:

```
ALTER TABLE Notas WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Notas_Endereco] 
FOREIGN KEY(nro_endere) REFERENCES Endereco (nro_endere)

ALTER TABLE Notas WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Notas_Agentes] 
FOREIGN KEY(id_agente) REFERENCES Agentes (id_agente)

ALTER TABLE Agentes WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Agentes_Pessoas] 
FOREIGN KEY(cgccpf) REFERENCES Pessoas (cgccpf)

ALTER TABLE Endereco WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Endereco_Pessoas] 
FOREIGN KEY(cgccpf) REFERENCES Pessoas (cgccpf)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_id_agente ON Notas (id_agente ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_nro_endere ON Notas (nro_endere ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_cgccpf ON Agentes (cgccpf ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_cgccpf ON Endereco (cgccpf ASC)
```