# Comandos de junções (join) em SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho algumas duvidas a respeito dos comandos `inner join`, `left join`, `right join` e `full join`, não sei se é apenas o `join` que faz as junções entre as tabelas, porem junto com ele vem esses comandos, e não estou conseguindo entender a finalidade deles, alguém poderia me explicar como eles funciona e quando usá-los?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Olha aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins e aqui: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Possível duplicada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99874/como-fazer-select-em-3-tabelas/99876#answer-99877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fins de exemplo, considere o esquema abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CROSS JOIN**

Quando queremos juntar duas ou mais tabelas por cruzamento. Ou seja, para cada linha da tabela FUNCIONARIO queremos todos os CARGOS ou vice-versa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**INNER JOIN**

Quando queremos juntar duas ou mais tabelas por coincidência. Para cada linha da tabela FUNCINARIO queremos o CARGO correspondente que internamente (INNER), em seus valores de atributos, coincidam. No caso de FUNIONÁRIO e CARGO os atributos internos coincidentes são codigoCargo na tabela CARGO e codigoCargo na tabela FUNCIONARIO. Para efetivarmos a junção das duas tabelas se fará necessário ligar (ON) as duas tabelas por seus atributos internos (INNER) coincidentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

Observando a tabela FUNCIONARIO suponhamos que o funcionário Tadeu não possui cargo associado a ele. Se desejarmos listar todos os funcionários com seus respectivos cargos, incluindo os funcionários sem cargos, poderíamos usar todo o poder da junção INNER JOIN adicionando ainda OUTER(EXTERNOS/OUTROS) Funcionários que não fazem parte do INNER JOIN, justamente àqueles sem cargos, como Tadeu. Podemos conseguir esse feito com a junção FUNCIONARIO/CARGO através da declaração FUNCIONARIO OUTER LEFT JOIN CARGO, que promove a junção interna (INNER) de todos os funcionários a cargos e lista ainda outros (EXTERNOS/OUTER) não associados.

Uma observação importante é que a ordem da ligação (ON) não faz diferença, ou seja: 
"ON (F.codCargo = C.codCargo)" é exatamente igual a "ON (C.codCargo = F.codCargo)"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**RIGHT OUTER JOIN**

Observando a tabela CARGO suponhamos que o cargo GERENTE, com código C3, não é referenciado/associado por/a nenhum funcionário na tabela FUNCIONARIO. Se desejarmos listar todos os CARGOS e seus respectivos FUNCIONARIOS, incluindo os CARGOS sem FUNCIONÁRIOS, poderíamos usar a junção RIGTH OUTER JOIN.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OUTER FULL JOIN**

Aqui juntamos o poder das junções (JOIN) internas(INNER), a listagem de todas as outras linhas não associadas, tanto do lado direito (RIGHT) da junção como do lado ESQUEDO (LEFT).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[@referência](http://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016)

Comment: Muito Obrigado Hoppy

Comment: Nada, é sempre bom ajudar. - Adicionei as imagens.

Answer (score 1):

Dener, todos fazem junções das tabelas com algumas diferenças:

Quando você utiliza o INNER JOIN com duas tabelas por exemplo,

tabela usuario e tabela cargo o, INNER join cria um conjunto de interseção como na matemática, como na imagem abaixo, o INNER JOIN traz todos os cargos relacionados por ids 4 e 5 da tabela de cargo que contem na tabela de usuário e ignora os demais, como no conjunto A e B.

```
SELECT * FROM usuario A INNER JOIN cargo B on B.id = A.id_cargo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já o LEFT JOIN cria um conjunto de relação entre as duas tabelas, porem da seguinte diferença:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario A LEFT JOIN cargo  B A.id_cargo =  B.id
```

Na consulta acima terá preferência a tabela especificada na esquerda usuário, então terá como resultado os usuários que possuem cargo e os usuários que não possuem cargo e o RIGHT JOIN faz o oposto disso, o ful JOIN faz a união entre as tabelas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Miguel! :)