# Diferença entre RIGHT JOIN e LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, join, relacionamento

Tenho um pouco de conhecimento em relacionamento de tabelas, li as respostas da pergunta sobre [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6442#6442), e entendi, teoricamente.

**LEFT JOIN**
Retorna todos os registros da tabela esquerda (tabela A) e as correspondências que existirem com a tabela direita (tabela B).

[image: Left Join]

**RIGHT JOIN**
Retornará todos os registros da tabela direita (tabela B) e as correspondências que existirem com a tabela esquerda (tabela A).

[image: Right Join]

Utilizando o exemplo abaixo:

**`Exemplo de LEFT JOIN`**

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela_a a
  LEFT JOIN tabela_b b
  ON b.nome = a.nome;
```

**`Exemplo de RIGHT JOIN`**

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela_b b
  RIGHT JOIN tabela_a a
  ON a.nome = b.nome;
```

Ambos retornam:

```
|   nome |
|--------|
|  Maria |
|    Bia |
| (null) |
| (null) |
| (null) |
| (null) |
| (null) |
```

Fiz um exemplo no [SQLFindle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d56008/2) para entender melhor.

---

### Pergunta:

> Teoricamente, existe a diferença, gostaria de entender para quais
>   casos reais se aplica a diferença, e o motivo de ter os 2 termos, de
>   modo que os 2 foram criados, e criados por alguém.

Obrigado.

Comment: Sua própria pergunta tem a resposta. e ambos vão retorna maria e bia porque tem nas duas tabelas.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4, certo, nas duas tabelas tem os valores, mas se as duas tabelas, forem diferentes, não traria nada. Até ai nada de mais. O que me intriga é utilizar `Right` e `Left`, e retornar a mesma coisa, no exemplo dado. Serio, não consigo enxergar diferenças praticas para os dois joins, e vamos desconsiderar o `Outer`.

Comment: Nas respostas desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101713/comandos-de-jun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-join-em-sql) explica as diferenças do left e right.

Comment: Obrigado @DenerCarvalho, mas especificamente minha dúvida não tem. Mesmo assim obrigado.

Comment: O que mais tem no stackoverflow é perguntas com join  ....

Comment: @David na duplicata está bem explicada a diferença entre Left e RIght e não são iguais, são contrários.

Comment: Sua pergunta parte de uma afirmação incorreta, impossível as duas situações retornarem o que disse. Coloquei umas colunas a mais no seu fiddle para ficar mais visível a diferença: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ba72/1 - Compare os dois diagramas que eu desenhei, que fica mais fácil. Tem exemplo de left e de right na pergunta indicada, e fica claro que não são iguais. Preste atenção no que acontece quando não tem dado em algum dos lados, e veja a diferença. Quando for assim, sugiro deixar um comentário na postagem original, fica mais organizado, e concentra tudo num lugar só.

Comment: Só pra ficar mais evidente: segue **Exatamente** o seu fiddle, com as duas _queries_, veja bem a diferença: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d56008/7 (preste atenção especialmente nos _null_ retornados. Isso faz toda a diferença quando você pega várias colunas numa situação real).

Comment: Um exemplo prático: Se você faz LEFT JOIN usuários e telefones, vai receber todos os usuários, mesmo que eles não tenham telefone, o que seria esperado. Se fizer RIGHT nesse caso, não vai listar usuários sem telefone. E se tiver um telefone sem usuário, ele vai aparecer só com RIGHT (o que não deveria nem existir, a princípio, mas isso é outro problema). O LEFT é importante quando a tabela da esquerda é o "eixo" da informação.  Um INNER não retornaria os usuários sem telefone também, e um OUTER traria telefones órfãos, o que não faria sentido se você está buscando o cadastro dos usuários.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experiência própria:

Dependendo de como você diagramar o seu `bd`, podem ter `n` tabelas, e dependendo da necessidade da sua `query`, você pode necessitar usar uma tabela como a principal da sua consulta, exemplificando com uma diagramação sem muito enfeite:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo tenho 6 tabelas, a `tabela 3` claramente é a principal do meu sistema, ela que faz ligação com todas as outras, poderia ser uma tabela de planos, por exemplo...

Se por acaso eu quiser criar apenas uma `query` trazendo informações referentes ao `id` da `tabela 3`, e outras informações adicionais de outras tabelas, por exemplo eu posso querer trazer todas informações referentes a `tabela 4`, mas que não possui nenhuma ligação com a `tabela 2` e 6, então eu poderia usar os recursos tanto do `left join`, quanto do `right join` para que ambos conseguissem atender a minha necessidade.

Em termos matemáticos, lembrando aquela aulinha de conjuntos, talvez fique mais fácil visualizar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo, eu preciso pegar informações que estão prioritariamente na `tabela 1` e não na `tabela 2`, e estão prioritariamente na `tabela 5` mas não na tabela 6.

Existem dois modos de se fazer uma consulta dessas, uma utilizando `sub-querys` (O mais recomendável quando existem condições na consulta do "sub-dominio", que não dependem apenas do relacionamento das tabelas), ou outra que é utilizando o recurso do `left join` e `right join` para trazer apenas os dados que forem necessários de uma ou de outra tabela, nesse caso o select ficaria mais ou menos assim [editar]

Comment: Entendi um pouco, se puder criar um exemplo seria incrível.

Comment: Eu lembro de uma `query` que eu trabalhei uma vez, que era de encaminhamento de alunos, eu tive que trabalhar com umas 10 tabelas em uma `query` só hsuashaushas, e era cheia de `inners`, `left`, e `rigth joins` ao mesmo tempo pra não trazer nenhum resultado `null`, criar um exemplo sem uma base é complicado. Se eu não conseguir hoje, depois procuro o código e posto aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Em termos de funcionamento não existe diferença somente em termos de conceito como o nome diz righ ou left direita ou esquerda se você usa

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela_a a
  LEFT JOIN tabela_b b
  ON b.nome = a.nome;
```

você vai trazer todos os resultados da tabela que esta a esquerda isso `tabela_a` MESMO os que não correspondam a tabela da direita. No caso se não haver comparação ele traz `null`.

Se você trocasse por right ele traria todos resultados da `tabela_b` (que esta a direita da tabela A).

Comment: Se em termos de funcionamento, não existe diferença, por que criaram os dois termos? Isso está me intrigando.... obrigado

Comment: simples
imagina uma query onde vc tenha varias tabelas colidindo ou nao informações,
é mais facil vc dizer de qual lado da consulta vai retornar tudo q ele encontrar do que alterar toda a query movendo os nomes de tabelas para se adequar a isso. so de mudar de left para right ja faz uma enorme diferença isso é muito util quando vc ajunta ou vai buscar informações em muitas tabelas de uma so vez.

Comment: entendo, e realmente faz uma enorme diferença,  mas ai utilizaria o `OUTER JOIN`, no caso o `IS NULL` no final do `JOIN`.

Comment: outer join he OUTRA coisa

cara como seu desenho mostrou tudo isso se baseia em teoria de conjuntos
da uma lida nisso aqui espero que te ajude

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Comment: citei essa resposta no inicio da minha pergunta. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: desculpe rsss, entao Outher join ou full join traz TUDO q tive na tebala a e b mesmo que nao tenha dados existentes que liguem as 2, resumindo ele faz uma bagunça e isso quase nunca tem aplicação logica. right e left ele traz os dados de uma tabela mas nao da outra caso nao tenha colidencia.

Comment: @David é mesmo só por uma questão de ser prático, você também poderia fazer os seus `if`s só com `>` sem o `<` certo? Então para quê ter os dois?