# Juntar Tabelas MySQL com nomes de campos similares

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas:

1. cliente : id_cliente, nome, sobrenome, data_nascimento
2. casa : id_casa, cor_casa, fk_cliente, fk_bairro
3. carro : id_carro, modelo, fk_cliente
4. bairro: id_bairro, nome

Eu quero realizar uma query nessas tabelas onde eu consulto todos os dados de clientes, cor de suas casas, nome dos bairros e suas casas.

O que eu tentei:

```
select `id_cliente`, `nome` as `nome_cliente`, `sobrenome`, `data_nascimento`, `cor` as `cor_da_casa`, `nome` as `nome_bairro` from `cliente`, `casa`, `bairro`;
```

O erro que estou obtendo:

`ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'nome' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Leitura Obrigatória: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Comment: Outra Leitura: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364602/mysql-inner-join-with-where-clause

Comment: Outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149407/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-right-join-e-left-join?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Quando duas colunas tem o mesmo nome  num Join (seja implícito, simplesmente listando os nomes, como seu caso ou explícito utilizando a palavra JOIN), você precisa dizer a qual tabela está se referindo ao usar o campo num SELECT.

Pode fazer com o nome completo da tabela:

```
SELECT cliente.nome AS nomedocliente FROM `cliente`, `casa`, `bairro`
       ------------ aqui você disse de onde vem o nome, não é mais ambíguo...
```

Ou com alias:

```
SELECT x.nome AS nomedocliente FROM `cliente` x, `casa` y, `bairro` z
      --- x é o ALIAS (apelido)              --- que você define aqui.
```

No caso, pode fazer `tabela AS alias` ou simplesmente `tabela alias`

Answer (score -3):

Para isto você precisaria em tese, utilizar Inner Join.

*[INNER JOIN](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-inner-join-vs-left-join/) seleciona registros que possuem valores correspondentes em ambas as tabelas.*

Através deste exemplo, voce conseguirá chegar onde você deseja.

Veja em funcionamento no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7e081/4)

```
SELECT cli.*, cs.cor as casa
FROM cliente AS cli
JOIN casa AS cs ON cli.id = cs.cliente_id
```